# How to get the shipping address programmatically in drupal commerce - what wrapper should i use?

Tags: 7, commerce

I need to get the shipping address (shipping country to be precise) programmatically in drupal commerce. I have the `$order` object. How can i get the shipping address?

EDIT - Ok i did this

```
 $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
 $shipping =  $order_wrapper->commerce_customer_shipping->value();
```

Now i need to wrap it up again, but i don't know the type

```
$shipping_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper(?, $order);
```

Whatshould i put instead of the question mark?

Answer (score 7):

Ok i did this in this way

```
function commerce_shipping_biagetti_service_rate_order($shipping_service, $order) {
  $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
  $shipping = $order_wrapper->commerce_customer_shipping->commerce_customer_address->value();
  //$shipping is an array containing all shipping data
```

Comment: Did you manage to get the $order object in your custom module? if so can you tell me how?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `commerce_customer_profile_load($profile_id)`, the profile id can be fetched from `$order->commerce_customer_shipping` variable since you have the order object.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 Ways to Find Customer/user shipping Address-

```
function get_user_shipping_address(){

global $user; 
$default_pid =commerce_addressbook_get_default_profile_id($user->uid,'shipping');
```

After getting profile id you can load profile and get customer name & Address

```
$profile_load = commerce_customer_profile_load($default_pid);
$first_line = $profile_load->commerce_customer_address['und'][0]['name_line'];
$landmark = $profile_load->commerce_customer_address['und'][0]['sub_premise'];
$postal_code = $profile_load->commerce_customer_address['und'][0]['postal_code'];
$state = $profile_load->commerce_customer_address['und'][0]['locality'];
$add[] = $first_line . ' ' . $landmark . ' ' . $postal_code . ' ' . $state;
return $add;
}
```

second way if you have $order

```
function get_default_address_of_customer_by_order_id($order) {
  $order1 = commerce_order_load($order);
  $shipping_id = $order1->commerce_customer_shipping['und'][0]['profile_id'];
  $address = commerce_customer_profile_load($shipping_id);
  $first_line = $address->commerce_customer_address['und'][0]['name_line'];
  $landmark = $address->commerce_customer_address['und'][0]['sub_premise'];
  $postal_code = $address->commerce_customer_address['und'][0]['postal_code'];
  $state = $address->commerce_customer_address['und'][0]['locality'];
  $add[] = $first_line . ' ' . $landmark . ' ' . $postal_code . ' ' . $state;
  return $add;
 }
```