# Get customer shipping information entered in checkout page, from shipping page

Tags: commerce

Following inline documentation on example shipping module api, I have an implementation of hook_commerce_shipping_services_info(), in which I set callback function for 'rate', 'details_form' etc.

I'm trying to calculate the rate based on the zip code entered by the customer, but the callback for 'rate' only takes two arguments, which are $shipping_services and $order. I dpm both objects, but didn't see any shipping information, entered on the previous page (checkout). The field [commerce_customer_shipping] has 
`Array
  (
   [und] => Array
     (
       [0] => Array
       (
         [profile_id] => 2
       )
     )
 )`

How do I get the values for the individual fields, such as address, city, and zip code?

Answer (score 0):

See the replacement patterns and give like as below, for example, 
[commerce-order:commerce-customer-shipping:field-name-line]. Use "-", not "_".

Comment: That's beside the point. The solution I was looking for is actually to use order entity wrapper. As what is demonstrated here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29158/how-to-get-the-shipping-address-programmatically-in-drupal-commerce-what-wrapp